# How do I add a New Line in Powershell Curly braces?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

How do I add new lines in Curly braces in Powershell?

**Code:**

```
"1. Files are `n different"   #This is Successful
{"2. Files are `n different" } #This fails
```

**Results:**

```
1. Files are 
 different
"2. Files are `n different"
```

I am trying to run an if statement for context.

```
if(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content $OriginalScript) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content $NewFilename))
    {$Database + " Files are different `n"}
```

Comment: The string in your if statement contains a single-quote-n, not a back-tick-n.  Do you see the same behavior with a back-tick-n?

Comment: still didn't work

Comment: In case the if condition is true the scriptblock **IS** executed, but as in your example the `\`n` is trailing you might not notice the difference.

Comment: do you have alternative solution you can post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curly braces are used to denote a scriptblock.

```
PS C:\> ({"2. Files are `n different"}).GetType().Name
ScriptBlock
```

If you do this

```
PS C:\> {"2. Files are `n different"}
"2. Files are `n different"
```

you are just outputting the content of the scriptblock, while they are meant to be executed:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {"2. Files are `n different"}
2. Files are 
 different

PS C:\> & {"2. Files are `n different"}
2. Files are 
 different
```